# Why isn't the PyQt5 QPushButton or QAction showing the desired image in Qtoolbar

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the following code to show an image of 16x16 or 16x12 in jpg and png format using QPushButton:

```
navbar=QToolBar()
btn=QPushButton()
btn.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("back.jpg"))) #or .png
btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_pressed)
navbar.addWidget(btn)
```

I also tried just using QAction like so:

```
navbar=QToolBar()
action=QAction(QIcon(QPixmap("back.jpg")),"back",self)
action.triggered.connect(self.btn_pressed)
navbar.addAction(action)
```

They always either show the text or the actual button but empty with no text or rendered image and I can't see where everything fails.

Comment: You're not setting any text for the QPushButton, so no text should be shown. Are you sure that the path to the image is correct and it's properly loading (`print(QPixmap("back.jpg").isNull())`)? Note that relative paths are always relative to the *working dir*.

Comment: yes all these files are in the same directory

Comment: im getting True to isNull()

Comment: I don't want text shown on the button I just want to see the image as the icon

Comment: Well, you've already found the answer: if `isNull()` returns `True`, no image has been loaded. So the file name is wrong, or the relative path is not correct because you're launching the script or interpreter from another path. Note that I clearly wrote about the *working dir*, which has nothing to do with "in the same directory".

Comment: first check `Current Working Directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )` - because some tools may run code with different `Current Working Directory` and code may search image in wrong place. And first you can test code with `"/full/path/to/back.jpg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @furas mentioned `Current Working Directory` depends on which command line path the file is started and it was constantly changing so the dependency on my relative path was causing the issue.